# Configurar launchsettings.json ASP.NET core en IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

Tengo el siguiente problema.
Cuando subo la APP a IIS no se me ejecuta hasta que no ingreso al navegador a "LocalHost:5060" .. La app es como un tipo de servicio no necesariamente se tiene que ingresar al navegador.

Cuando la ejecuto en VS con IIS Express me funciona correctamente.

Por lo que estuve leyendo en el launchsetting se configura asi
(Pero me sigue sin funcionar)

**launchsetting:**

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "WSOsdop": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5060"
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "use64Bit": true,
      "ancmHostingModel": "OutOfProcess"
    }
  },
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5060",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  }
}
```

**Project File:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RunPostBuildEvent>OnOutputUpdated</RunPostBuildEvent>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ChilkatDnCore" Version="9.5.0.92" />
    <PackageReference Include="ChilkatNativeLib" Version="9.5.0.92" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Quartz" Version="3.3.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="108.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.8.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Federation" Version="4.8.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.8.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.8.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.8.*" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Log\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Gracias.

Comment: no entiendo tu problema, IIS es un servicio de alojamiento web, si está arrancado da igual si el navegador esta abierto o no

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: "para que en el IIS se ejecute sin abrir el navegador" Quizá tienes confundido los conceptos ya que esa frase no tiene mucho sentido, intenta detallando el problema o caso de uso de tu aplicación

Comment: @NicolasOñate El problema es ese, la app no se me ejecuta, hasta que no ingrese a LocalHost:5060

Comment: @javdromero ahi reformule el problema

Comment: claro, no recibe petición hasta que la invocas, pero arrancada está, la pregunta que me hago es dónde quieres invocarla?

Comment: Por favor, podrías cambiar el título de la pregunta a: ¿Cómo hacer que mi applicación ASP.NET Core arranque inmediátamente en IIS sin esperar a la primera petición?. Así la gente podrá encontrar la solución más fácilmente, porque en realidad lo de launchsettings.json no tiene nada que ver. Pensabas que launchsettings.json podría resolver tu problema, pero launchsettings.json no es el problema sino otro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`launchsettings.json` no tiene ningún efecto cuando la aplicación está desplegada en el IIS. Se usa desde el Visual Studio y también cuando la ejecutas desde la línea de comandos con `dotnet run`, por ejemplo:

```
dotnet run --launch-profile WSOsdop
```

De forma predeterminada las aplicaciones en IIS arrancan a demanda. Es decir, tal y como estás experimentando, arrancan cuando reciben la primera petición. Mientras tanto no hay proceso de trabajo `w3wp.exe` (World Wide Web Working Process). Sin embargo esto se puede cambiar para que la aplicación esté siempre ejecutándose. El requerimiento de que esté siempre ejecutándose no es tan raro, la aplicación puede tener procesos en segundo plano que requieran estar siempre ejecutándose, por ejemplo un planificador de trabajos, o cualquier otra cosa que se te ocurra. Estos suelen implementarse a través del interfaz `IHostedService`.

Para configurar la aplicación de manera que siempre esté ejecutándose hay que seguir los siguientes pasos.

**Asegurarse de que está instalada la característica *Application Initialization* en el IIS**. Aquí te dejo un enlace con instrucciones para instalar esta característica https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/iis/configuration/system.webserver/applicationinitialization/

**Configurar el *Application Pool*** con los siguientes parámetros desde la ventana de *Advanced Settings*:

- `Start Mode`: `AlwaysRunning`
- `Idle Timout (minutes)`: 0

**Configurar *Application Initialization*** en el `web.config` dentro del elemento `<configuration>`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true">
        <add initializationPage="/" />
    </applicationInitialization>
</system.webServer>
```

Pregunta relacionada:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23731746/alwaysrunning-not-working

Enlaces de interés:

https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/522#issuecomment-164381473
http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/iis-8-0-application-initialization-for-fast-startup-everytime

Comment: Muchas gracias Jesús!